# Backtracking in java: choose to maximize the benefit

Tags: java, algorithm, backtracking, knapsack-problem, n-queens

I have a list of soccer players(20), and for each player I have his level of play (a number between 1 and 10 that specifies the quality of the player) and his position on the field (Goalkeeper, defender, midfielder or forward). In addition, there is a list of pairs of incompatible players, who can not play together in the main team.

**What I need to do is form a team with an goalkeeper, four defenders, three midfielders and three forwards, that maximizes the total game level (defined as the sum of the game levels of their
players), and such that there are no incompatible player pairs in the formation.**

I want to apply **backtracking** but I'm confused, I don't know how to face this problem. Any ideas? I was thinking of having an aux List where I can save the players that I choose and use as a recursion base case when I have 11 players in my aux List, save all posible solutions and choose the best... Please, help..